# Why am I receiving a blank authentication header from IIS for this request?

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, iis-7

In my organization (standard windows with domain/Active Directory environment) we have a vendor application that uses IIS 7.5 with several IIS applications under a single website.  To use the API for this product, an installation executable is run that adds an additional IIS application as part of the single website.  The installation offers basicHttp or Windows authentication, and I've chosen Windows.

I'm now following their instructions to use the API (the C# version of the Get a Name sample): http://www.documentation.newdawn.com/api/

I've created a C# console app in Windows Visual Studio 2012 and used the Add Service Reference menu item to consume the service URL and create the client classes.

My only change to the code in the URL is to use windows authentication instead of their BasicHttp example:

```
using JustWareAPIClientConsoleApp.JustWareAPI;

namespace JustWareAPIClientConsoleApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JustWareApiClient client = new JustWareApiClient();

        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "<domain>";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "<username>";
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "<password>";

        Name n = client.GetName(123, null);

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + n.Last + "," + n.First);

        client.Close();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I've made no changes to the App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="JustWareApi" messageEncoding="Mtom">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://<server>/JustWareAPI/JustWareApi.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JustWareApi"
                contract="JustWareAPI.IJustWareApi" name="JustWareApi" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I run the client sample I get the following error when it reaches the GetName method call:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.
```

Based on my choice during the API install of windows authentication, I was expecting a response header of something like 'NTLM,Negotiate', not a blank/null value.

Unfortunately I don't know IIS well, but my gut is telling me there is some setting at the site or application level that the API install didn't set correctly, and I'm not getting back a valid authentication header.  Can anyone tell me why this header would come back like this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have this problem because you're not authenticated through IIS. Try to specify the NTLM credentials type, instead of Windows.

Comment: after changing the clientCredentialType attribute of the transport element to 'Ntlm', I got the same error, but with 'Ntlm' in place of 'Negotiate'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting pointed in the right direction by Alberto, I found that Windows Authentication wasn't "installed" for IIS.  Directions for that here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/zroiy/archive/2008/08/17/missing-windows-authentication-provider-for-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008.aspx

Then it must be enabled:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

After these steps I am no longer getting the IIS authentication error.